# Targetline on barchart from pivot table

Tags: excel

I want to add a vertical target line on a horizontal bar chart. The problem is that the source data is a pivot table and not just a table.

I’m building an interactive dashboard and therefore I need the data to be in a pivot table instead of a normal table. I cannot find anything on this except how to add a target line from a normal table.

Can somebody help?

Regards,

Ryan

Comment: Unless you're planning to do this programmatically, you'd be better off asking about it at [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: The pivot table is not the source data, but rather a view on the source data.
If you need the pivot table I would add the target as additional data to your source data

Comment: I know that the pivot is not source data, but the chart is connected to the pivot and need to keep it this way, because every day data is being added and I work with slicers that are connected to these pivot tables. If there is a vba code which does the trick it would also solves my problem. I tried putting the target in the pivot and change the chart type for the target data, but there isn’t a chart that I could find that does the trick.